# Data Conversion In ETL SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm working in ETL process where I have a column in a table varchar with data as `28JUN1952`.
This will always be in this format i.e. 2 digits for date, 3 letters for months and 4 numbers for years.

I was able to convert this into a date column by I need this to come in `yyyyMMdd` format i.e. `28JUN1952` become `19520628`. I was able split the years months and date, but unable to add a padding in the month if it's a 1 digit month for e.g. `Jan` or `Feb`.

Is there any other way to convert the data format or any other alternative to add a padding?

I need the conversion in SSIS only.

Comment: Can you post the formula you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest route will be to add a Script Transformation.

1. On the Input and Output tab, expand the Output 0, select Output Columns, click Add Column. 2. Rename Column to something like ccyymmdd and change the data type. I'm not sure what your target type is (int32, string?) but I'll assume string as I'm lazy
2. On the Input Columns tab, select the string date source column (assuming it's called srcDate)
3. Inside the script task, assuming C#, use code like this

Inside script task

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    DateTime x = DateTime.MinDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Row.srcDate, out x))
    {
        Row.ccyymmdd = x.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle NULL values however you wish
        // Assign "known bad value"
        // Row.ccyymmdd = "99991231";
        // Or set the null property to true (preferred)
        Row.ccyymmdd_IsNull = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @d varchar(20)='28JAN1952';

SELECT replace(CONVERT(date,RIGHT(@d,4)+SUBSTRING(@d,3,3)+LEFT(@d,2)),'-','')
```

Comment: I cannot add SQL command there. I need the some SSIS Conversions.